# Common-mode voltage protection of a device

Tags: common-mode, instrumentation

[This](https://www.dataq.com/resources/pdfs/manuals/di710_manual.pdf) datalogger manual has a warning about excessive common-mode voltage on its 5th page.

> ...data acquisition device you have purchased and are about to use is NOT an ISOLATED product. This means that it is susceptible to common mode voltages that could cause damage to the device.

I'm planning to use a metal enclosure which will include some power supplies, a couple of amplifiers, and this logger. Two amplifiers will be connected to this logger as single-ended. The signal to the amplifiers will come from two transducers 15 meters away from the enclosure by BNC cables.

The system is already prepared and has its own protection and earthing. I just need to move the system to a new enclosure plus this datalogger.

My questions are the following:

1. If I measure the common-mode voltage as they suggest and warn on 5th page and find out it is alright, is there still a risk in another environment for the same setup? I mean, I will check common mode in the workplace but some other technicians will install it in a harsh environment for measurements. Should they also check the common-mode voltage there before setting up and powering up?
2. The manual says the common-mode voltage might damage the logger. How about if I add 15 V Zener clamps before the inputs to the logger, wouldn't that protect the logger? Or if there is common-mode voltage, how do I eliminate it?
3. The transducer amplifier system (the signal source) must be earthed because of lightning protection etc. But the manual says the logger also must be earthed. I'm wondering, in that case, would there be ground loops? Is this logger's earth connected to its analog ground or are analog ground and earth isolated? Can I verify that and be sure by doing a continuity test?

Comment: What does the supplier recommend?

Comment: No more details in manual and I couldnt get an answer and I have hurry. My questions are: Can commonmode voltages differ due to different AC mains of the same setup? Can zeners provide a possible CMV exceeding 15V? Can I check by continuity of earth and analog input are isolated?

Answer (score 1):

The device is capable of measuring 30VDC with respect to it's 0V, probably chassis.
This means that there is no real "common mode" voltage at play here. Unless you're using two inputs as differential, in which case neither of the lines may exceed 30VDC.

I do not see what you're are confused about. The manual is very clear, with pictures how to wire it up, and how not to wire it up.

1) Yes, you should check. But if the source is isolated, it might give ambiguous results, like half mains voltage. If the source is not isolated, and the signals are above 30VDC or 21VAC, additional circuitry might be required.

2) It would protect the logger, but it might damage the source by excess currents. I would assume the logger already has transient protection build-in.

3) Yes there will be ground loops. But the manual already provides a solution for that.[image: ground loops]

Comment: But I will use single ended.  Can there still be CMV? How should source and loggers earthed that time? What if I earth the source side and do not earth logger side? And if I earth both side why would there be ground loops because logger's earth and logger's ground are isolated or not?

Comment: **Both sides are always earthed.** You just not supposed to connect shield between the two devices in differential mode. Look at the red current path in the image.

Comment: I plan the single ended signal goes to the logger with a BNC cable. BNC's shield is connected to the earth of the source. Is that okay to wire BNC's + and shield to logger's + and AGND? (BNC's shield not to the logger's earth) Did I get you correct? I would be glad if you can illustrate this for single ended.

Comment: @doncarlos It looks like you have no choice in single ended mode. If the ground loop distorts the signal too much, you will have to add an isolator.

Comment: but isnt in datasheet shows agnd and earth of the data logger isolated?

Comment: pls see pg 19 (i will not connect a pc to the logger)

Comment: it seems like front and backend are isolated. thats why i wassnt sure if agnd and earth are wired